# mongoose query .where/.and after .populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I need to test if a user has the given id, a project with a specified id and a role with a given name.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    roles: [{
            project: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Project',
            },
            role: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Role',
            }
    }]
});
```

and

```
var RoleSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
            type: String
    }
});
```

I tryed to .populate and then apply .where, but .where does nothing.
Using an .and after populate does not work either.

How to solve this in mongodb/mongoose?

Thank you!

//EDIT
Right now I have something like that, which does not work (.where does nothing) and it is really not beautiful:

```
    User.findById(userId)
    .populate({
        path: 'roles.role',
        match: { 'name': roleName}
    })
    .where('roles.project').equals(projectId)
    .exec(function(err, data){
        data.roles = data.roles.filter(function(f){
            return f.role;
        })
        if(!err){
            if(data){
                if(data.roles.length == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

When I do what Kevin B said:

```
  Role.findOne({name: roleName}, function(err, data){
    if(!err){
        if(data){
            User.findById(userId)
                .and([
                    {'roles.project': projectId},
                    {'roles.role': data._id}
                ])
                .exec(function(err2, data2){
                    if(!err2){
                        if(data2){
                            console.log(data2);
                        }
                    }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The .and query just does nothing here...

Comment: Show us your query... even not working code is of value here.

Comment: In this case, you would **first** have to query the role collection for roles with the given name, then you would have to query the users that have said roles and projects by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm just doing comparisons in the program instead of the database.

```
User.findById(userId)
.populate('roles.role')
.exec(function(err, data){
    if(!err){
        if(data){
            if(data.roles.find(function(element, index, array){
                return element.project == projectId && element.role.name == roleName;
            }))
                return callback(true);
        }
    }
    return callback(false);
});
```